# how can i solve package problem for abp framework?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, abp

i am trying to run this project, but every time i run the solution or every layer, it says some packages are missing in another layer.
I tried to to download the packages missing, but still gives me the error, some packages are missing in another layers.
I tried to update, the same thing happened.
I made sure of nuget is right, but still the same thing.
I tried to run dbmigrator alone, i got some pages missing.
Here is screenshot, and it is just an example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using project references out of your solution, try `dotnet build /graphBuild`. That will build all the dependent projects in a graph order.

See [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-process-overview?view=vs-2022#graph-option) for more information.